# Drawing on a view(in a scroll-view) is consuming too much memory in ipad devices

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have a view added on a scrollview(maxZoomScale = 1, minZoomScale=0.25). view-frame have a size of near-about(2000, 2000). I have written code for drawing a path(for ~8000 points) in the drawRect of the view. Whenever scrollview's zooming ends, i flagged the view's drawing. Now each time drawRect is called it consumes huge memory (~16MB). Due to this iPad reboots giving memory warnings.
Please any body help me to solve out this issue...

Comment: 16 MB is not a lot; you should definitely be able to use that much without it crashing. Try using Instruments to see how much you're actually allocating. If you're using temporary objects in `-drawRect:` you can use NSAutoreleasePool to improve memory management.

Answer (score 0):

Investigate CATileLayer. You should not be drawing a 2000x2000 view; most of the stuff there is offscreen.

Comment: i want smoothly drawn path while zooming in/out. CATiledLayer makes it to be drawn in parts.

Comment: Maps uses tiles and while you can see the discontinuity, it really isn't the end of the world.